# Sender Email address not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I updated System Admin e-mail address(Jenkins > Configuration). But, Still Receiving Notifications from Jenkins with address (address not configured yet nobody@nowhere)
Jenkins Version - 2.249.1-lts

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the "Extended E-mail Notification" settings and set your SMTP server etc?

Comment: Yes, I have setup Extended E-mail Notification Settings. Is there any way to debug the issue where the issue lies. Bdw I run jenkins in container.